# Label in tableview cell not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, label, tableview

I am creating a tableview with one cell, and retrieving data from Firebase to display as a label `firstName`. The data is being retrieved (I have checked by using a print statement) however the label is not showing up, even though alpha is set to 1. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class userTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var profileData = [profileStruct]()
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
    var email = ""
    var phoneNumber = ""
    
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         getProfile()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      //   tableView.register(profileCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell")
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }
     
     
     struct profileStruct {
         let email : String!
         let phoneNumber : String!
         let firstName : String!
         let lastName : String!
     }
     
    @IBAction func signOut(_ sender: Any) {
        KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func getProfile() {
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {
                    snapshot in
            self.firstName = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["firstname"] as? String)!
            self.lastName = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["lastname"] as? String)!
            self.email = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["email"] as? String)!
            self.phoneNumber = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["phone number"] as? String)!
            print(self.firstName)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
    }
    

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return 1
     }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      //  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")!.frame.size.height
        return 500
    }
     
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileCell") as? profileCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
         cell.firstNameLabel?.text = "first name: " + firstName
         cell.lastNameLabel?.text = "last name: " + lastName
         cell.emailLabel?.text = "email: " + email
         cell.phoneNumberLabel?.text = "phone number: " + phoneNumber
         return cell
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a breakpoint on `guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileCell") as? profileCell else { return UITableViewCell() }`, you need to check whether the `as? profileCell` is successful, and check whether the `Data Source` is invoked.
2. If the first step is working, you need to check the `profileCell` UI layout. Open the `Debug View Hierarchy`, and check whether any cell on tableView.

Comment: And the name of `userTableViewController` & `profileCell` should start with a capital letter.  The way you write this applies to declaring an instance.

Comment: The breakpoint is being called, as for the debug view hierarchy, I can see the wire outline of a cell but I cannot see a label

Comment: @sam Is it return a `profileCell` row in `DataSource`?

Comment: You can see the kind of  `TableViewCell` in `Debug View Hierarchy`, if the kind is `UITableViewCell` & not a `profileCell`, you need to register the `profileCell` in `viewDidLoad`.
But if the cell is `profileCell`, you need to check the UI layout in class `profileCell`.

Comment: The items are now showing! But the constraints are not being applied, any reason why?

Comment: Which way do you use that add constraints? If you use code, you need to set the view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getProfile() {
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
    self.firstName = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["firstname"] as? String)!
    self.lastName = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["lastname"] as? String)!
    self.email = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["email"] as? String)!
    self.phoneNumber = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["phone number"] as? String)!
    print(self.firstName)
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 })}
```

Comment: Try with call dataSource and delegate hopefully it will work

Comment: I have used this code, however still no labels are showing up, even ones with set text. Is there anything else that i  can try?

Comment: Yes, You can store your firebase data into one model class as array or dictionary then try to display on tableview. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to show the email instead of the first name here.

```
cell.emailLabel?.text = "email: " + firstName
cell.phoneNumberLabel?.text = "phone number: " + lastName
cell.firstNameLabel?.text = "first name: " + email
cell.lastNameLabel?.text = "last name: " + phoneNumber
```